# Renaming multiple items in a database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have seeded a lot of data for my database in rails 4.  The data that I imported was entered manually by hand by a user of gigabot (using the gigabot) API.

The problem that I have is that I am trying to list "club nights" in my case but I am getting lots of duplicates back as the names are similar but not identical.  Is there any way I could group the items where is the name contains a certain word then they would group together.

Currently these are my only validations

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  validates :name, presence:true, uniqueness:true
  validates :location, presence:true
  validates :description, presence:true, uniqueness:true
end
```

Here is some of  example data that the table currently displays

Name

DC10
Amnesia
Circo Loco @ DC10
Sankeys
Sankeys Ibiza
Cocoon
Privilege Ibiza
Circoloco at Dc 10
Space
Space Ibiza

If you look at the above example you will see that some of the clubs are repeated.  I would like to clean up the table so it would only have "DC10" as 1 club and all the clubs which have DC10 in their name are grouped together.

SO in the example above instead of having 10 seperate clubs it would be 6.

DC10,
Amnesia,
Space,
Sankeys,
Priviledge,
Cocoon.

Comment: "I am getting lots of duplicates back as the names are similar but not identical" This isn't clear, please share some examples of the data and your queries.

Comment: I would suggest editing your answer and showing the table structure with some example data, and what you want it to end up as.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) method from ActiveRecord.

This will allow you to update all the values of fields in a collection. So now you just have to get a collection that you're certain fits together.

I suggest doing something like [SIMILAR for postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP). So you could do something like:

```
pattern = '%DC10%' # This can be as advanced as you need it
collection = Club.where('name SIMILAR TO ?', pattern)
collection.update_all(name: 'DC10')
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very difficult task. Most likely you won't be able to come up with a regex that can capture your intention.

For example let's imagine you have a club `Space` and other entries

```
Void @ Space
Outer Space
Inner space
Alien in Outer Space
```

they all end in Space but which ones should be regrouped ? My examples was a big exaggerated, but it sounds like you are dealing with a lot of data and cases like this one may occur.

Do you not have any other fied which could help you regroup records together ? Like GPS coordinates, city, etc. ?